# how to invoke method of current class with parameter?

Tags: php, class

```
array($this, 'methodName');
```

This is how I invoke a method of current class. But I wish to pass a parameter which is of string type along. How do I go about it?

`call_user_func_array used` to pass array of parameter

I tried:

```
array($this, "{methodName}($param)");

But it says method is not found
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to **pass around** a method as callback **including some parameters**? I mean, simply `$this->methodName($param)` won't do, right?

Comment: second argument of `call_user_func_array` can be used to pass parameters

Comment: The documentation of [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) also contains examples. Have you read it?

Comment: @DileepKumar, i do not want to use call_user_func_array as the param is expecetd to be array and its very slow..

Comment: @112233 How can you say it will be slow? do you have stats?

Comment: @deceze, correct, I want to access a method from another method of same class

Comment: @DileepKumar, I refer php net.

Comment: "Accessing" it is as simple as `$this->methodName($param)`… do you need to ***pass the method around as callback?!*** Just want to ensure you're not barking up the entirely wrong tree here.

Comment: yes i want to pass the method as callback

Answer (score 0):

To pass a method as callback together with some arguments in one single value, an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is best:

```
$param = 'foo';
$callback = function () use ($param) {
    return $this->methodName($param);
};
```

If the callback is supposed to accept additional parameters:

```
$callback = function ($more) use ($param) {
    return $this->methodName($param, $more);
};
```

`$callback` can be invoked via any of the mechanisms to call `callables`, e.g. `call_user_func($callback)` or simply `$callback()`.

Note that this does not work in ancient versions before PHP 5.4.

Comment: For additional parameters, you could instead add $more as an additional use variable, i.e. `use( $param, $more)`

Comment: @slevy1 Not if that parameter is going to be passed at *call time*.